# Can linux lite run Quartus II

Tags: linux

Recently in my engineering course we started to use Quartus, now I want to get it on my computer, but I only have a Mac laptop. So now I am looking for light linux distributions to run Quartus on without wrecking my laptop. Now i am going to try Linux lite. Does anyone have any other possible solutions to this problem?

P.S. This is obviously for program FPGAs

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: So what exactly is the question again? There is a version of Quartus for Linux. But I guess you know that already. Are you asking if you can install linux on your Mac? This is definitely an off-topic question.

Comment: If you can find the installer for Quartus II for linux then yes. Otherwise use a current version. http://fpgawiki.intel.com/wiki/Quartus_for_Linux

Answer (score 1):

### Consider running Quartus inside a VM.

> So now I am looking for light linux distributions to run Quartus on without wrecking my laptop.

You don't need a particularly "light" Linux distribution. Rather, choose something that's widely used, has a community around it, and has decent support. This way you are *less* likely to have problems, both with your Mac and with Quartus.

> Now i am going to try Linux lite.

For the reasons above, I recommend sticking to something more mainstream. I've never even heard of "Linux Lite", and their [website](https://www.linuxliteos.com/) does not exactly inspire confidence.

The most popular options, with the largest communities are currently probably Ubuntu, Fedora, and Debian. But ask someone else and you'll probably get different answers ;)

> Does anyone have any other possible solutions to this problem?

Yes. Installing any other OS alongside MacOS brings some risks (if you do, at the very least back up *everything* you care about). Also, if the other OS doesn't boot or WiFi doesn't work or whatever, it's a pain to troubleshoot, having to reboot to MacOS, etc.

You might be a lot better off by running the OS of choice (which could also be Windows) inside a Virtual Machine, inside MacOS. This sandboxes the OS for Quartus inside the VM software, greatly reducing the risks of damaging your existing MacOS installation.

I'm not particularly familiar with the virtualization landscape on MacOS, but I hear [Parallels Desktop](https://www.parallels.com/) is a Mac-specific solution. [VMWare](https://www.vmware.com/) is a reasonably popular option that's also available for MacOS. Thirdly, there's [Oracle Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), of which the open source version is quite popular, and it reportedly also works on MacOS.

One thing to pay attention to with virtualization: it might be tricky to get the virtualized OS to talk to specialized hardware. This might be the case for you, if the FPGA programmer is connected directly to your Mac. If it is USB, look for information on "USB passthrough".

Comment: If using VirtualBox when configuration your VM under System => Acceleration -> Paravirtualization, select None, otherwise your real time clock will run slow.  You could also require Oracle's extension pack to access USB devices. It's all relatively painless. The ModelSim-Intel FPGA Edition would require 32 bit libraries as well.

Comment: Are you sure you recommend disabling of paravirtualization? that's why VMs work so well these days.